# incorporate list of file names into loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of files that I want to open and search for a string. My code works fine for a single file.
This is made harder by the fact that I want to search for a different string in each file. For example:

```
**File    | String**
one.txt | ra
two.txt | nd
three.txt | om
four.txt | st
```

My question is, would it be easier to write an entire new script to do this or is it worth modifying my existing script to incorporate this feature?

```
import re
import io
prompt = ">> "
configfile = input(prompt)
interfaceno = input(prompt)

with open(configfile) as infile, open('output2.txt', 'w+') as outfile:
        copy = False
        for line in infile:
                    if line.startswith("interface " + interfaceno):
                                copy = True
                    elif line.startswith("interface"):
                                copy = False
                    elif copy:
                                outfile.write(line)
```

The script opens the file given as input and then searches it for the string given as input. It then starts copying when it reaches the string given as input and stops copying when it reaches the word "interface" which appears in all the text files. This copied section is then written to another file.

The desired output would be a list of each file name with a yes or no dependent on if the string was found.

```
**File    | String**   | Found?
    one.txt | ra   | yes
    two.txt | nd   | no
    three.txt | om | no 
    four.txt | st  | yes
```

Comment: Wrap your code in a function

Answer (score 0):

Keep your existing code, but start a new program.
This new one reads the first file you posted, with **File** and **String** columns.  Read that file line by line, splitting each line into the file name and search string.  Put those into variables and print them out.  You'll do this in a loop.

Now, go back to your first program.  Take the file-specific parts (below the prompt line) and make this the body of the loop you just wrote.  You may have to adjust a couple of variable names, but this is essentially the program: you already have something to handle one file; just put it inside a loop to handle lots of files.